poetry add quixstrems doesn't work due to rocksdict library dependency
I am trying to add a package dependency to my pyproject.toml file using poetry add quixstreams. The installation returns an error because one of the dependency packages called rocksdict cannot be installed.
I tried running poetry add rocksdict but that also returns the following message:
  - Installing rocksdict (0.3.23): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for rocksdict (0.3.23)

  at ~\pipx\venvs\poetry\lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chooser.py:74 in choose_for
       70Γöé 
       71Γöé             links.append(link)
       72Γöé 
       73Γöé         if not links:
    ΓåÆ  74Γöé             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
       75Γöé 
       76Γöé         # Get the best link
       77Γöé         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
       78Γöé 

Cannot install rocksdict.

I was able to pip install quixstreams via anaconda terminal and I have the package folder under anaconda3\lib\site-packages. I pasted the folder to \AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\src-zTdCedyO-py3.10\Scripts where the VM created by poetry lies but still cannot recognize the import quixstreams command in my py file.
